# memory alllocation wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I tried to have a dynamic memory allocation inside my application. If I try to allocate memroy in `OnInit()` then the application crashes.

Currently I'm using the lastest stable version of wxWidgets 3.0.4 with Visual Studio 2010.

If I comment `#define BUFFER` the application works as expected.

my main.h:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp {
    public:
        virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MainWindow : public wxFrame {
    public:
        MainWindow(const wxPoint& position, const wxSize& size);
        ~MainWindow();

    private:
        void setupUi();

        int *buffer0;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

#define BUFFER
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool MyApp::OnInit() {
    MainWindow *main = new MainWindow(wxPoint(20, 20), wxSize(300, 200));
    main->Show(true);

    return true;
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxPoint& position, const wxSize& size) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Frame") {
    setupUi();
#ifdef BUFFER
    buffer0 = new int(1000);
    memset(buffer0, 0, 10 * sizeof(int));
#endif
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
#ifdef BUFFER
    delete[] buffer0;
#endif
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void MainWindow::setupUi() {
    wxBoxSizer *bsMain = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxStaticBox *sbInfo = new wxStaticBox(this, wxID_ANY, "INFORMATION");

    bsMain->Add(sbInfo, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 15);
    SetSizer(bsMain);
}
```

Comment: Consider the difference between `int x(10);` and `int x[10];`.

Comment: See..., `int buffer0 = new int(100)` would mean creating a variable to a pointer with 100 as its value... `int buffer0 = new int[100]` on the other hand means to create an array/pointer with 100 bytes allocated to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
buffer0 = new int(1000);
```

you allocate memory for 1 (in words: one) `int` and initialize it with `10000`. Then with

```
memset(buffer0, 0, 10 * sizeof(int));
```

you set `10 * sizeof(int)` bytes starting at `buffer` to zero. You access memory that isn't yours.

Since you use `delete[]` in your destructor I guess you wanted to write

```
buffer0 = new int[1000];
```

or even

```
buffer0 = new int[1000]{};
```

to initialize the `int`s with zero without having to use `memset()`.

---

### The Real<sup>*(tm)*</sup> Answer:

Use

```
std::vector<int> buffer0(1000);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I used the wrong brackets

Comment: In the long run you (still) use the wrong data type ;p

Answer (score 3):

There is difference between

```
buffer0 = new int(1000); // allocate sizeof(int) bytes
```

and

```
buffer0 = new int[1000]; // allocate sizeof(int) * 1000 bytes
```

Your program has undefined behaviour, because you allocated `sizeof(int)` bytes but by

`memset(buffer0, 0, 10 * sizeof(int));`

you want to set `sizeof(int) * 10` bytes to 0. You are accessing memory to which you don't have access.
Use square bracket to create array `new int[1000]`.